# Lotus notes: open view from outline with categoryname

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there a method to open a view from outline using 'categoryname' property ?
I try to do this using 'Named element' and put into formula for the named element but i can't use @command formula in that field.
So there is another one way to use categoryname in outline ?
thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use type "Action" instead of "Named element". You can use @Commands then.

To open a view at a certain category you'd add the formula

```
@Command([OpenView];"yourView"; "yourKey");
@Command([ViewCollapseAll]);
@Command([ViewExpandWithChildren])
```

Comment: Ok, i try your solution and it work ! Thank's !  But if i want to completly hide the docs under other category like 'picklist categoryname' do  ?

Comment: Then you would use a Page with an embedded view which shows the one category only. You'd include the Page into outline as 'Named element'.

Comment: you can use a form as well as a page for a single category view...  and set a SaveOptions field to "0" so it is never saved.